# How to link to data URL without Firefox adding "unsafe" prefix

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, csv, download

I'm trying to create a download link in an angular app that makes data in a model downloadable as a CSV file. I have it all working except for the actual download link. Using filesaver.js is blowing up unit tests in Karma so I'm exploring just doing it manually.

Below is what I have. In the controller:

```
var blob = new Blob([data.join('\n')], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'});
$scope.downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

In the view, I have:

```
<a ng-href="{{downloadUrl}}" download="ttester.csv" id="download">Download</a>
```

The issue is this opens a new page in Firefox 20 with the URL "unsafe:blob:af775c64-dcb1-864a-8eaa-adebe7f101a7", notice the "unsafe:" prefix. Removing that prefix downloads the data correctly, but without the filename I want.

What am I missing in my hyperlink to make it work? I expect it to open a download dialog with the filename tester.csv for the file.

Really appreciate any help

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3889

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following code that will create the blob, a fake link and will dispatch a click event on this fake link. Note that no new page should be opened but you will be directly prompted with the save dialog box.

```
var blob = new Blob([data.join('\n')], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8'});
var url  = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
var link = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a");
link.href = url.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'teams.csv'; // whatever file name you want :)

var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initEvent("click", true, false);
link.dispatchEvent(event);
```

You can see a working Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmc2y/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the issue wasn't with Firefox but with Angular. I had to add a whitelist entry for data URIs.

Comment: @Jazzuzz how did you add it to the whitelist?

Comment: @winkerVSbecks I just added this line in my routes file : `$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|data):/);` to allow that pattern through

Comment: Of the several answers on SO, this was the only one that worked for me with Firefox and Chrome. I also did a `setTimeout` with `URL.revokeObjectURL`.